# Android Compare Lockscreen pattern captured from 2 sources

Tags: java, android, xposed-framework

I am working on an android app where I am saving the a lock pattern.
While the user enters a pattern while powering on the screen, I am checking if it is the same as the saved pattern.

I am saving the pattern in the application using: https://github.com/haibison/android-lockpattern/

The problem is that both are in different formats:

1) lockpattern Object captured while powering on the screen:

```
[(row=1,clmn=0), (row=0,clmn=1), (row=1,clmn=1), (row=2,clmn=1), (row=1,clmn=2)]
```

2) And this one i am capturing using haibison's method:

```
char[] pattern = data.getCharArrayExtra(LockPatternActivity.EXTRA_PATTERN);
String lockpattern = new String(pattern);
```

Can you please provide some examples/links.

Should I not use haibison's method?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an Encrypter before starting the Lockpattern-Intent in order to get a proper representation from haibison's char-array , e.g. LPEncrypter (https://bitbucket.org/haibison/android-lockpattern/wiki/Encryption):

```
AlpSettings.Security.setEncrypterClass(context, LPEncrypter.class);
```

E.g. a simple representation for this pattern:

[Simple Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APWWZ.png)

Habisons char array without the Encrypter is like this:

```
[3,9,7,7,c,9,3,7,e,c,e,a,5,6,2,4,0,e,a,7,3,9,3,4,b,8,e,9,a,c,9,7,6,6,e,8,e,8,d,0]
```

using the Example-Encrypter with
                        String[] ids = new String(pattern).split("[^0-9]");

you'll get `[1,-,2,-,3,-,6]` which should be easy to convert into your lockpattern-representation.